# HDFS & Spark - rewrite part of huge file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

How to rewrite part of huge file (more than 1TB)?

I store data in parquet files, they splitted by max block size. Is it possible to update some records and rewrite only that blocks without rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest create another spark job and read that particular file with entire hdfs offset path like hdfs://user//part-000-. This would only read this file and then change your data accordingly and write the data in a separate hdfs directory making a df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(). This would return you a single file which you will hadoop fs -cp  /old/directory/ and remove the old file hadoop fs -rm /. This would easily solve your issue without hampering other directories.